# How to prevent injection in GET-parameters in where-clause

Tags: get, typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 I created some records with different sys-categories assigned to them. These categories are passed to the page as GET parameters (like this: ?pcat=7).

To prevent injection I use `intval = 1` in the following where clause within a database request:

```
10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {

          [...]

          where {
            cObject = COA
            cObject {

               20 = TEXT
               20 {
                  data = GP:pcat
                  if.isTrue.data = GP:pcat   // only if GP is set
                  intval = 1                 // to prevent SQL-injection
                  noTrimWrap = | AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=| |
               }

            }

          }

          [...]

        }

        renderObj = ...

}
```

But is that enough? Do you have a hint for me how to make this even safer?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

`intval` is enough. That way you can be sure it will always be an int and you can't do any SQL injection with just an int.

For non-int values you should use markers instead of directly placing them from the GP variable into your where. Markers in TypoScript select are escaped and quoted correctly to prevent SQL injection. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html#markers for more information on that.

I'd advice to always use markers, even if you can use `intval` to make it safe. If you're used to using the markers method you'll never accidentally forget `intval` or forget it shouldn't be used like that with non-int values.

Your TypoScript would become something like this:

```
10 = CONTENT
10 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    [...]
    where {
      cObject = COA
      cObject {
        20 = TEXT
        20 {
          value = ###pcat###
          if.isTrue.data = GP:pcat
          noTrimWrap = | AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=| |
        }
      }
    }
    markers {
      pcat.data = GP:pcat
      pcat.intval = 1
    }
  }
  renderObj = ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe this documentation in the [TYPO3 Security Guidelines](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/Security/GuidelinesIntegrators/Index.html#typoscript) can help you as well.

Comment: Thank you for the hints with the markers! Can you help me again how I could apply this to my code example above (especially the part where I check if the GP is set)?

Comment: I added an example of altered TypoScript to my answer.

Comment: `intval` should be applied in the markers area, so the marker `pcat` will **always** be an integer - not only in the `where`-clause.
The where-clause ifself could be simplified (because you can use markers and `where` has stdWrap-properties):
`where = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = ###pcat###
where.if.isTrue = ###pcat###`

Comment: You're right about the `intval`. I forgot to remove it, but moving it to the marker is even better. The where clause you're proposing won't work because it's only part of the where clause as I understand it. So it will need a noTrimWrap for the spaces at least. And aren't the markers only applied to the processed where string? If so, using the marker in `if.isTrue` won't work.